# How to save value to session from f:form.select and then use this value

Tags: typo3, extbase

In my extbase extension I use select form for select city. I want to save the selected city in a session, then use the city's value to search. Please, tell me the direction to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could send your form data to an action which will fetch a result through your repository or you can store the argument as a session.

Fluid form example:

```
<f:form action="search" controller="">
    <label for="city-select">Select the city to search for</label>
    <f:form.select name="searchString" id="city-select" options="cities" optionValueField="title" optionLabelField="title" />
</f:form>
```

Controller class example:

```
/**
 * The action search.
 *
 * @param string $searchString
 */
public function searchAction($searchString)
{
    // Do a search by a repository function...
    $result = $this->yourRepository->findbySearchSDtring($searchString);
    // code ...

    // Or save it to session and do other stuff.
    if ($GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser) {
        // if the user is logged in, store it in the current logged in fe_user session.
        $myData = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('user', 'mySessionData', $searchString);
    } else {
        // Otherwise store it in the user session.
        $myData = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'mySessionData', $searchString);
    }
    // code ...
}
```